# Any example of when one would pronounce the word "a" with a long A sound?

Tags: pronunciation

I am trying to think of any example when one might be correct in pronouncing the word "a" with a long A sound. With the word "the," one would use the long E sound only when the word is followed by a word that begins with a vowel sound, that is, "thee atrium of thuh building can hold 50 people." But I cannot think of any appropriate time for using the long A sound. Can anyone else? Thanks.

Comment: There is none. The corresponding rule for the indefinite article is the _a/an_ rule; _a_ /ə/ and _the_ /ðə/ both precede consonants, and _an_ /ən/ and _the_ /ði/ both precede vowels. So there is no reason for someone to use /e/ for the indefinite article. When one hears /e bɪɡ dɔɡ/ (instead of /ə bɪɡ dɔɡ/, which is normal), it is usually interpreted as the speech of someone learning to read aloud, haltingly.

Comment: I am assuming you're asking when the indefinite article *a* is pronounced like /eɪ/. The answer is - any time you want. Often, the pronunciation /eɪ/ adds more emphasis.

Comment: This isn't just ***a*** question - it's ***the*** 64,000 dollar question on everybody's lips.

Comment: I agree with @FF - when seeking to emphasize the article, it's pronounced with the long a sound.

Comment: This is another case where some people simply pronounce things differently.  I'll tend to use "ae" rather than "uh" when I want to emphasize that there is only one of the things, using "uh" most of the other times.  Other people will use "ae" quite a bit more often (even though they are perfectly literate).

Comment: Define "long a". The only time I can think of folks saying /a:/ for the indefinite article is when they're struggling for the following word.

Comment: @tchrist *Did John find the marbles he lost? The reason I ask is that I did notice (long a) marble on the floor of the car.* This emphasises the fact that there was just one marble. *Did Jane get her one-mile swimming certificate? No, but she did get (long a) certificate*.

Comment: @WS2 Well yes, if you pronounce it with the [eɪ] of *day* rather than the [ɑː] of *father* (or rather, the [ə] of *about*). I don’t really understand John Lawler’s somewhat categorical dismissal of any sort of /e/ or [eɪ] pronunciation. I doubt your scenario never occurred to him, so I wonder what his thinking is here. Perhaps John really did lose his marbles. :)

Comment: @tchrist Ha ha! I promise you, and John, that the pun was entirely unintended. The only reason I chose marbles was because I noticed some belonging to my grandson lying on the floor and have been taking care not to stand on one in my stockinged feet all evening.

Comment: @WS2 I thought I was the only one who still talked about walking around in one's stocking feet any longer. :)

Comment: @WS2, ə disavowal of your perfectly appropriate pun is entirely implausible :-) *eɪ marble* implies a singularity in my mind as well. The last time I contradicted John Lawler, I ate crow, so beware.

Comment: @ScotM Well he does know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 4):

For reasons I don't fully understand myself, a long version of a vowel is generally perceived as stronger and more obvious than it's short version. Especially with words such as "a", "an", and "the", you are colloquially allowed to pronounce them with the long version of their vowel for emphasis and clarity ("an" isn't pronounced as if it was "**A** n", though). I suspect this has cognitive and physiological influences.

I might ask you, "Does that answer your question?" You might then reply "Well it answers **A** question...but that's not th**E** question."

This is a common conversational way of drawing attention to the article. If you ask someone to hand you a wrench, and they hand you a whole sack full of wrenches, you might say "I just need **A** wrench" - which is considered a bit rude when you could just say "I just need one wrench, not a bunch of wrenches." As "a" is singular, pronouncing it as a long/strong **A** draws attention to it.

Now, you could just be louder and clearer and still pronounce these words with a short vowel sound. "I just need **u**h wrench." It's not wrong, but again for some reason loudly pronounced short vowel sounds are often part of mockery or even foolishness, as with "duh", "uhhhh", "um", and their various ilk.

So drawing attention with emphasis to a long vowel sound draws attention to the word choice itself, while adding emphasis to a short vowel sound tends to have a connotation that is insulting rather than merely brisk/rude. I think this is likely related to the shape of the mouth and facial expression that one makes when voicing these sounds, but I'm just spit-balling there.

I don't know if this is th**E** answer, but it's an answer. **I** think it's ok, but it's really up to yo**U**.

(Note: I apologize that this post doesn't actually contain an acrostic. Sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

If your "a" is an indefinite article, it is usually pronounced in the short form  /ə/ in ordinary speech, unless you want to stress it . But if you want it to mean the first letter of the English alphabet, it will be pronounced as a long "a" /ˈeɪ/.

Examples:

- What are those guys doing over there?  That's a /ə/ team, a /ə/ basketball team.
- How come you guys have finished before all other groups?  Because we are "a"/ˈeɪ/ team.
- Johnny is really very bright. He is a straight-A /ˈeɪ/ student.